# Why didn't Nick Fury do something and where was he?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

Nick Fury plays a very important role in creating the Avengers. But in the events of *Captain America: Civil War* Fury was nowhere to be seen. In the movie, the Avengers team is seen falling apart. So why didn't Nick Fury do something then? Where was he?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [screenwriters](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/herocomplex/la-et-hc-nick-fury-civil-war-20160509-snap-story.html), there was no room for him:

> **I'm curious. Where was Fury?**
>
> **Stephen McFeely:** I'm curious too!
>
> **Christopher Markus:** We called him, but he let the line blink. Primarily it felt like one too many possible opinions. We didn't want
>   him to take one side or the other, because that's not his place in the
>   universe. And then we didn't want another, "Is he still with the
>   government? Is he opposed to the government but supporting the
>   government?" It got to be the potential for a lot more polemic
>   discussion **that the movie did not have room for**.
>
> He's the guy who put it together. He's been the sort of parent figure to the Avengers. Let the parent go away, and see if the kids can
>   handle this. See if the kids can be who they're supposed to be without
>   that governing voice. Um... and they didn't do that good  of a job.